# VBA - Copy a row and insert into row under it

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Prefacing by saying I don't have any VBA experience, but I need this data sorted fairly quickly.  I have a Sage 300 Invoice Import I need to do. I can sort this data via formulas after it's made a second time.  The root of the problem is that this data needs to actually be put into two rows per one row, but excel skips lines.

I have a partial snippet of code that would work for me, but I get an outside reference error when I run it.

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Any tips or hints?  I would love it if it would just copy that row to the one below it exactly, until it hits an empty row.

I read the sort comment and it dawned on me that I could recopy the data and sort by a unique value so that it all came in as it was supposed to - but I'd like to know the VBA code anyway.

Comment: Where did you place the code? Did you create a sub procedure? There is nothing wrong with the code itself. I have no idea why on earth you'd use VBA to simply copy one row and paste it directly below but I guess that is your own business

Comment: Why don't you just use 'sort' to sort??

Comment: Are you simply trying to sort the data or do more to it after it is sorted? I guess that part isn't very clear

Comment: There are over 2000 rows to add.  I could do it by hand, but I haven't.  Basically, with the Sage 300 Invoice Import, you I need the same line to get data from a static spot in two rows - the easiest way to do this is to just copy all the rows again.  I use my selection and the error happens

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub copyRowToBelow()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1") ' <~~  Change this

    Do While (rng.Value <> "")
        ' Insert a row below the current one
        rng.Offset(1).Insert

        ' Copy the current row and paste it into the row we just inserted
        rng.EntireRow.Copy rng.Offset(1)

        ' Set the range declaration for 2 rows below the current one
        Set rng = rng.Offset(2)
    Loop
End Sub
```

The marked line ("Change this") can be declared in the code, or you can swap it for `Set rng = ActiveCell` if you want it to run off of the cell the user is working on at the time of running the macro.

Comments are not necessary for the code, they are there purely to help you learn more about VBA.

Comment: What's the purpose of the loop? Just to make sure you don't copy an empty row?

Comment: Yes, in a way. It's also to make sure that the procedure actually ends at some point (and indirectly, avoiding a stack overflow). The loop makes the code more flexible by not relying on a hard-coded range, allowing for datasets of varying size. Of course, it also introduces the limitation that your dataset must be continuous.

Comment: Oh, somehow I had missed the `set rng = rng.Offset(2)` so I didn't understand how it was iterating over anything.  My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Select cell from which you want to start copying and run this macro

```
Dim myCell
Set myCell = ActiveCell

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set myCell = ActiveCell
Wend
```